# getting one value from array output using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

My array:

```
result = {"ids":[{"tid":"121"}],"tid":[{"tid":"121"}]}
```

I want to display the value of tid inside ids and tid inside tid using ajax but I don't know how to do it. I have tried `result.val(result.ids.tid)` but that gives me undefined. I have also tried `result.val(result.ids["tid"])` with and without quotes on tid but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can get the output of 121 from the result array?

Comment: That isn't an array, that's JSON.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: `result.ids[0].tid`

Comment: Open up your dev console, if you don't have resutlt available then paste `var result = {"ids":[{"tid":"121"}],"tid":[{"tid":"121"}]}`. then type result and press enter. You should now be able to traverse into the data and figure out how this works, so you can do it next time as well. Teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, it's not JSON. It's an object.

Comment: What do you think JSON (Javascript Object Notation) is @smarx?

Comment: JSON is a data-interchange format. (See http://json.org/.) If we had JSON here, we would be holding a string, and we would need to deserialize it to get an object.

Comment: You do know that JSON is short for Javascript Object Notation, right @smarx? It is the very first words of the very first sentence of the page that shared you a link to.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Maybe this will help: `var json = '{"ids":[{"tid":"121"}],"tid":[{"tid":"121"}]}';` (Note the quotes, since JSON is always a string.) `var result = JSON.parse(json);` Now, we have an object in `result`, just like in the question here.

Comment: @smarx please quit trying to be patronizing. What you're describing is a string (because it is quoted) You do not have to go the additional step of `JSON.parse(json)` if you're directly dealing with the object's notation. JSON elements, must be quoted, not the whole thing. If you paste the object into jsonlint.com it validates *as* JSON.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The reason I point it out is because this confusion frequently causes problems for JavaScript developers. If they don't know the difference between a JSON string and a JavaScript object, they end up double-JSON-encoding things or trying to index into a string they thought was an object.

Comment: That is because a string *is not JSON*. If anything, that is where the confusion is. C'est la vie - we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @smarx @JayBlanchard You guys are both correct but talking about two different things. The OP created a javascript object. To turn the object into JSON, he could have used `JSON.stringify(result)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: At that point @jk the object (valid JSON) would become a string, which is totally unnecessary as you've shown with your answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard JSON is a textual representation of data, so it can only ever be held in a string.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The OP created a javascript object, not JSON.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Happy to be done here, but one last thought, because I do think the distinction trips up a lot of JavaScript developers. (This confusion doesn't happen much in other languages, since the language syntax doesn't overlap as much with JSON.) Presumably if you saw `var result = 42;` you would not consider there to be any JSON involved. Hopefully that helps to explain why there is no JSON involved in `var result = [...];` or `var result = {...};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object that contains arrays of objects. You should reference the array index to get to the object inside the array.

`result.ids[0].tid`